# C# generic helper method that needs to work on any type provided the type implements a method

Tags: c#, generics

I've got a case where I want my generic helper method to work with many types, but the generic method requires that the type implements a method but I don't have access to the types implementation to add an interface.

Here is a basic example:

```cs
public static class Utils
{
    public delegate float DistanceFunc<T>(T t, T other);

    public static int FindNearestOtherIndex<T>(this T t, IList<T> others, DistanceFunc<T> distanceFn)
    {
        int nearestIndex = 0;

        float minDist = float.MaxValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < others.Count; i++)
        {
            float dist = distanceFn(t, others[i]);

            if (minDist > dist)
            {
                minDist = dist;
                nearestIndex = i;
            }
        }

        return nearestIndex;
    }

    public static int FindNearestOtherIndex(this Vector2 t, IList<Vector2> others)
    {
        return FindNearestOtherIndex(t, others, Vector2.Distance);
    }

    public static int FindNearestOtherIndex(this Vector3 t, IList<Vector3> others)
    {
        return FindNearestOtherIndex(t, others, Vector3.Distance);
    }
}
```

In this case I want to add a "FindNearestOtherIndex" helper to both the Vector2 type and Vector3 type, but these types don't implement any interface that says they need to have the distance function available and I don't have the ability to modify these classes to add one as they are part of a library.

Is this pretty much the best you can do with C# without using reflection to check if the type has the method?

Or is there some way to do something like this:

```
public static int FindNearestOtherIndex<T>(this T t, IList<T> others) where T : float T.Distance(T,T) { /* ... */ }
```

I'm guessing not because I haven't been able to find anything online about it, but asking here incase my search terms were bad and there is actually something like this.

Comment: Why not pass the function in using the delegate?

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry, I'm not sure I follow?

Comment: Why not just use `public static int FindNearestOtherIndex<T>(this T t, IList<T> others, DistanceFunc<T> distanceFn)`?

Comment: Ah I see, the reason I'm trying to find a way around that is in this case its not a big deal, but in the future if I have more complicated functions, it would become quite unwieldly to need to pass potentially many functions in each time you want to call the generic helper method. Basically I want it to "feel" more like a native method rather than an awkward helper extension method.

Comment: OK, then inject it in first, once, and you're good. I'll throw an answer up in a tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at using a simple injection method. Add these methods:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _distanceFns = new();

public static void AddDistanceFunc<T>(DistanceFunc<T> distanceFn)
{
    _distanceFns[typeof(T)] = distanceFn;
}

public static int FindNearestOtherIndex<T>(this T t, IList<T> others) =>
    t.FindNearestOtherIndex(others, (DistanceFunc<T>)_distanceFns[typeof(T)]);
```

Now you can, at the start of your program, do something like this:

```
Utils.AddDistanceFunc<Vector2>((v, w) =>
    (float)Math.Sqrt((v.X - w.X) * (v.X - w.X) + (v.Y - w.Y) * (v.Y - w.Y)));
```

Now you can simply call it like this:

```
int d = Utils.FindNearestOtherIndex(x, new List<Vector2>() { y, z });
```

Comment: Ahh I see, just cache the distance functions in a lookup table effectively, I guess I could go a step further and use reflection on ones that haven't been added yet to automatically add them since there is no compile time T type filtering to ensure you have a distance function for that type anyway, which was one of the things I was kinda hoping for. But yeah I guess this is probably as good as it gets, thanks for the reply.